# Selecting a date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

If you select 06.05.2021 in the first datepicker, then the second date picker should not select anything before 06.05.2021. The script works with the yy-mm-dd format. The dd.mm.yy format does not work. How to fix it?

Format "yy-mm-dd" works:

```js
$("#start").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  minDate: new Date(),
  maxDate: '+2y',
  onSelect: function(date) {

    var selectedDate = new Date(date);
    var msecsInADay = 86400000;
    var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);

    $("#end").datepicker("option", "minDate", endDate);
    $("#end").datepicker("option", "maxDate", '+2y');

  }
});

$("#end").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p>Start: <input type="text" id="start"></p>
<p>End: <input type="text" id="end"></p>
```

Format "dd.mm.yy" does not work:

```js
$("#start").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
  minDate: new Date(),
  maxDate: '+2y',
  onSelect: function(date) {

    var selectedDate = new Date(date);
    var msecsInADay = 86400000;
    var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);

    $("#end").datepicker("option", "minDate", endDate);
    $("#end").datepicker("option", "maxDate", '+2y');

  }
});

$("#end").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p>Start: <input type="text" id="start"></p>
<p>End: <input type="text" id="end"></p>
```

Comment: Which datepicker are you using? [fengyuanchen/datepicker](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker#events) doesn't seem to have an "onSelect" event. Might you be using the [jQuery UI datepicker widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)?

Comment: @showdev yes,  jQuery UI datepicker, The problem is that the dd.mm.yy format breaks the script

Comment: Did you see this Demo: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's [`Date()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) does not recognize the format "dd.mm.yy".
Consequently, `selectedDate` will be `null`.

```js
console.log(new Date('15.04.2021'));
```

One solution is to parse the string into a recognized timestamp.
Below, I'm using [datepicker's](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) `parseDate()` function:

> **$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, options )**
> Extract a date from a string value with a specified format.

```js
const msecsInADay = 86400000;

const $pickEnd = $("#end").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
});

$("#start").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
  minDate: new Date(),
  maxDate: '+2y',
  onSelect: function(date) {

    let parsedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', date);
    let selectedDate = new Date(parsedDate);
    let endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);

    $pickEnd.datepicker('option', {
      'minDate': endDate,
      'maxDate': '+2y'
    });

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p>Start: <input type="text" id="start"></p>
<p>End: <input type="text" id="end"></p>
```